# Ввод в TextBox только заданных слов

Tags: c#

Подскажите код, который разрешит вводить в textBox только заданные мной слова.

Например, в textBox1 я задал слово html, а в него ввели php, надо чтобы выводилось сообщение, что параметр задан не верно, еще помогите с выводом числа в label. Пишу на с#, долго мучаюсь с этим кодом.

Comment: интерфейс на WPF или WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйся ComboBox... запиши туда свои значения и все. другие значения не введёшь во время работы программы..

Answer (score 1):

самая обычная валидация

```
if (word == "html") label.setText(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывод числа в Label

```
myLabel.Text = myNumber.ToString();
```

В параметре метода `ToString()` при работе с вещественными числами можно, если надо, указать формат. Варианты формата приведены в [официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).